# can't get out of async loop

Tags: python, while-loop, async-await

I'm trying to make a command which starts after the variable `benbotLoop` is set to 2, and stops after `beenbotLoop` is set to 1. But whatever I do, it just doesn't seem to stop looping. Here is my code:

```
idint = int(0)
benbotLoop = 1

displayName = input("What's the display name? ")
benbotLoop += 1

async def main():
    global idint
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get("http://benbotfn.tk:8080/api/cosmetics/search/multiple", params={"displayName": displayName}) as r:
                data = await r.json()
                json_data = await r.json()
                list_type = json_data[idint]["type"]

                if list_type == "Outfit":
                    list_id = json_data[idint]["id"]
                    benbotLoop = 1
                    print(list_id)
                    print(benbotLoop)
                else:
                    idint += 1


while benbotLoop == 2:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use a while loop on an async function, you need to return something to let the loop know that it's done. (`loop.run_until_complete(main())`), where you want the loop to end, put `return`.